# CSVReader returning null value for first column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, opencsv

I am working on a Java program and one of the main requirements involves uploading a csv file which will in turn update the database.

Everything seems to be working fine when I upload a file expect for every row the first columns value is read in as null, while the the rest of the columns are populated correctly.

It is my first time using spring, hibernate and maven on a project so I'm learning as I go. It's probably something simple but I've tried everything I can think of for this and would very much appreciate some help.

```
public static List createMembers(CSVReader csvReader) throws Exception{   
    ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<Member> strategy = new  ColumnPositionMappingStrategy <Member>();

    strategy.setType(Member.class);

    String[] columns = new String[] {"forename","surname","dob","player", "address1","address2","address3","address4","town","county","postcode","mobile","home","work","email","otherInformation"}; 

    strategy.setColumnMapping(columns);

    CsvToBean csvToBean = new CsvToBean();
    //Set column mapping strategy
    List list = csvToBean.parse(strategy, csvReader);

    return list;
}
```

--

```
public void importCSV() throws Exception {
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(*filename*));
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    List list = XXCsvToObject.createMembers(csvReader);
    //logger.info(csvReader);

    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    for (Object object : list) {
        Member member = (Member) object;              
        session.persist(member);
        logger.info(member.toString());
    }       
}
```

--

```
@Table(name="MEMBER")
public class Member{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String forename;
    private String surname;
    private String dob;
    private String player;  
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String address3;
    private String address4;
    private String town;
    private String county;
    private String postcode;
    private String mobile;
    private String home;
    private String work;
    private String email;
    private String otherInformation;
```

--

Peter   Jones   23/02/2010  Y   15 Main street  Peckham         Peckham London  SE15 3AA
    331518315           Peter.jones@gmail.com
Mary    Jones   04/06/2002  Y   15 Main street  Peckham         Peckham London  SE15 3AA
    576846958           mary.jones@gmail.com
John    Jones   10/09/1979  N   15 Main street  Peckham         Peckham London  SE15 3AA
    576864694           john.jones@gmail.com

Comment: So the problem is that `forename` is null for every parsed object but all other fields contain the correct values? Does `Member` contain a setter for `forename` (without any typos in its name)?. Also, could you add some rows of the CSV file to your question?

Comment: Yes that is correct. No typos in the getter or setter either.

public String getForname() {
  return forename;
 }
 public void setForname(String forname) {
  this.forename = forname;
 }

I have added some sample rows to the question

Comment: But this is a typo: `setForname` - should be `setForename`

Comment: Wow! Very embarrassed, I won't tell you how long that's held me back! Thanks so much!